# Converting to long long int in C using strtoull()

Tags: c, hex, long-integer

What im trying to do is take in an input txt file filled with thousands of lines of hexcimals values and convert them to long long ints.

Example:

```
0x7f1a91026b00
0x7f1a91026b03
0x7f1a91027130
0x7f1a91027131
0x7f1a91027134
0x7f1a91027136
0x7f1a91027138
0x7f1a9102713a
0x7f1a9102713c
```

but im reading them as strings, how do i convert these to a type long long int? Ive been told i can use the strtoull() function but im not understanding how it works. This is what i have currently:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
        // if there is no input then print an error
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    char linestring[BUFSIZ];
    char **ret;
    while (fgets(linestring, sizeof(linestring), file)) // reads the entire file until it hits Null
    {

    strtoul(linestring, ret, 16);
    printf("%s\n", ret);
    printf("%s\n", linestring);

    }


    fclose(file);
}
```

This isn't working obviously but could someone please explain to me what i should do?

Comment: You obviously want to store the result of strtoull in an integer or else why would you call the function for? Try reading the documentation of the function before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sscanf, e.g.:

```
  long long int data;
  sscanf(linestring, "%llx", &data);
```

**EDIT:**

Or follow the user3386109's advice, with respect to C++11

Comment: You shouldn't use long long unless you know that the data are actually of signed format. Use unsigned long long, or better yet uint64_t. Also, sscanf is a really slow and potentially dangerous function, use strtoull instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `strtoull` function *returns* the converted value, so you want something like this

```
char *endptr;
unsigned long long value = strtoull(linestring, &endptr, 16);
printf( "%llx\n", value );
```

Comment: `strtoull` is available from C++11

Comment: @VolAnd Who cares, this is tagged C. And strtoull has been available since C99.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to strtoul should be NULL or point to a valid memory address. In your code ret has undefined value.

```c
char *ret;
unsigned long value;
```

and

```c
value = strtoul(linestring, &ret, 16);
```

may be what you need. `&ret` is the address of `ret`, which is a `char*`.

Comment: Downvote comment : `strtoul`? it returns unsigned long!!! see `strtoull` at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoull/

Comment: I am just refering to the example code above. But you are right, the numbers are too big for long on a LLP64 architecture.